# Default height issue if height is not given in ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-grid

I have not given any height to ui-grid, but ui-grid takes default height 347px.

I have just given ui-grid without any height,

```
<div id="grid1" ui-grid="{ data: myData }" class="grid"></div>
```

Below is the plunker,

http://plnkr.co/edit/3JEROJZcDPaRoDhbwi5q?p=preview

How to get auto height, without specifying any height.

Answer (score 0):

[Updated Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/hBa1aAsaTB4LFDKWl0qP?p=preview)

Use `ui.grid.autoResize`.

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid" ui-grid-auto-resize ></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.autoResize']);
    $scope.gridOptions.minRowsToShow = $scope.myData.length; //define minimum row to display
```

Please check and let me know.

Comment: Thanks Khalid, it works. But I have dynamic row height. I hve one background also. Below is the plunker,

Comment: how to set auto height for this?

Comment: Hey, have you gotten an answer for this? I'm facing the same thing